# Linker: "__fltused" is multiply defined if I don't use a float in the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, sdl-2

The full output is this (just one error), and release builds don't seem to encounter the same problem

```
SDL2.lib(SDL_stdlib.obj) : error LNK2005: __fltused already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(fltused.obj)`
```

I've recompiled SDL2.lib with /MTd and as a static library, and ensured it was the only library of it's name on my system.

it gets bizarre though: Putting a floating point operation anywhere in my program allows it to link without problems:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    return 0;  // will not link
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    float flt = 0.0f; // gets around optimization
    return int(flt); // will link
}
```

That's not ideal of course, what could be the underlying issue here?

Comment: This is a sign that you are linking to more than one version of the C runtime libraries. You said you recompiled SDL2.lib with /MTd; what is your application compiled with? It should be compiled with /MTd, too.

Comment: @CodyGray - aye, SDL2 and my executable are both /MTd for debug, /MT for release, I triple checked since that seems to be the most common reason

Comment: That is really the only thing it *can* be. The CRT is what defines the `__fltused` symbol. Are you linking in *any* other LIB files that might have been compiled with a different version of the runtime libraries?

Comment: @CodyGray - My other libs are `OpenGL32.lib;glu32.lib;winmm.lib;imm32.lib;version.lib;` unfortunately... so I'm at a loss.  Not sure why using a float would allow it to link either

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, from what I remember, this gets around it.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" { 
#endif 
int __fltused=0; 
#ifdef __cplusplus 
} 
#endif
```

Comment: I tied this, but it turned out to be `int _fltused=0;` with only one underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with how SDL2 was compiled.

It's not enough that the library is compiled with the /MTd or /MT switches for static linkage.  The library requires `HAVE_LIBC` be defined during it's compilation as well, in order for it to statically link into the C runtime correctly.